# Problems with lifetimes when one instance of a struct needs a reference to another

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a simple game with SFML and Rust, but the borrow-checker is proving to be my greatest enemy on this journey.

There are a bunch of cases where SFML needs a reference to another object. In the code below, I need a reference to a Font or else Text doesn't show anything to the user.

Problem is, I've tried a bunch of things and the reference itself never lives long enough. It obviously works if I create the Text object on the draw method, but I would like to avoid creating things inside the main loop of the application.

Is this a case where I should take a look onto the unsafe operations? Is there a combination of Rc, RefCell, Box, etc. that meets my needs?

Please try to explain me what I should be doing and what is wrong in my current mindset, if possible.

```
extern crate sfml;

use sfml::system::{ Clock, Vector2f };
use sfml::graphics::{ Color, Font, RenderTarget, RenderWindow, Text, Transformable };

pub struct FpsMeter<'a> {
    position: Vector2f,
    clock:    Clock,
    value:    f32,

    text:     Text<'a>
}

impl<'a> FpsMeter<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let font = match Font::new_from_file("assets/sansation.ttf") {
            Some(fnt) => fnt,
            None      => panic!("Cannot open resource: sansation.ttf"),
        };

        let mut text = Text::new_init(
            &format!("FPS: {}", 0),
            &font,
            20  
        ).expect("Could not create text");

        FpsMeter {
            position: Vector2f::new(0., 0.),
            clock:    Clock::new(),
            value:    0.,

            text: text,
        }
    }

    pub fn set_position2f(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32) {
        self.position.x = x;
        self.position.y = y;
    }

    pub fn restart(&mut self) {
        self.value = 1. / self.clock.restart().as_seconds();
    }

    pub fn draw(&mut self, window: &mut RenderWindow) {
        self.text.set_position(&self.position);
        self.text.set_color(&Color::white());

        window.draw(&self.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with rust-sfml, so I might be misreading your issue, but it should look like this.
You have a `Font` and `Text` (that you don't control, they're constructed for you by the library) where `Text` holds a reference to `Font`. Simplified:

```
struct Font;
struct Text<'a> { font: &'a Font }
```

Then you have a `FpsMeter` (that you do control) that has a `Text` field. Again, simplified:

```
struct FpsMeter<'a> {
    text: Text<'a>
}
```

now, if that's the case, I don't think you can create `Text` (or at least `Font`) in the same method where you create your `FpsMeter`, as the reference to `Font` can't escape the stack frame of the constructor function. You will need to pass a pre-built `Text` to your constructor. For instance:

```
impl<'a> FpsMeter<'a> {
    fn new(txt: Text<'a>) -> FpsMeter<'a> {
        FpsMeter { text: txt }
    } 
}
```

or possibly:

```
impl<'a> FpsMeter<'a> {
    fn new(fnt: &'a Font) -> FpsMeter<'a> {
        FpsMeter { text: Text { font: fnt } }
    } 
}
```

[toy example on the playground](http://is.gd/Lmi17s)

Comment: Well, I'll probably end up writing a singleton FontManager or something like that, so removing the Font from the constructor isn't really a problem.

But I'm still a bit curious about how can I make components, if they start requiring everything to be created outside the struct scope.

Comment: If your component owns its subcomponents (instead of a reference to them) you can build them all in one place. In this case, Font is created reading from a file (relatively expensive operation), and there would typically be various pieces of Text created with that one font, so it makes sense to load all needed fonts in the beginning and just share references to them.